# I need to be able to count the letter grades

Tags: java

I have been able to calculate letter grades with inputs and how many grades have been entered. However, I need to find a way to count how many of each letter grade has been entered, please help.

```
import java.util.*;


public class GradePercent {

    static final int THRESHOLD = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of courses: ");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter " + n + " scores: ");

        int[][] students = new int[3][n + THRESHOLD];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            students[0][i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        int bestScore = getBestScore(students);
        setGradeRange(students, bestScore);

        for (int i = 0; i < students[0].length - THRESHOLD; i++) {
            char grade = getStudentGrade(students, i);
            System.out.println("Grade " + i + " score is " + students[0][i] + " and grade is " + grade);
        }
        System.out.println("Total grades: " + n );
    }

    public static char getStudentGrade(int[][] students, int index) 
    {

        int grade = students[0][index];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        {
            if (grade >= students[1][i]) 
            {
                return (char) students[2][i];
            }
        }
        return 'F';
    }    

    public static void setGradeRange(int[][] students, int bestScore)
    {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
            {
                students[1][i] = bestScore - (10 * (i + 1));
                students[2][i] = ('A' + i);
            }
    }

    public static int getBestScore(int[][] students) {
        int bestScore = 100;
        return bestScore;
    }
    public static int[] countLetters(char[] chars) {
        int[] counts = new int[26];
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
            counts[chars[i] - 'A']++;
        return counts;
    }
}
```

Comment: The last method was me trying to count the letter grades.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community (for starters, you could tell us what the problem is)

Comment: The assignment asks for me to allow a user to plug in any number of courses and grade for that class as a number. Then the program should be able to output what is score letter grade is and how many courses are being taken and finally percent of each letter grade compared to total course number.

Comment: I have been able to do everything but have not been able to find a way to get the percent of letter grades compared to total courses

Comment: Oh, I understand the task.  I just don't know what the problem you are having is... this is not an assignment-writing service - do you get any errors? If so, what do they say?

Comment: I understand that I don't want it to be written for me, just need a hints on how I can approach this because I have tried everything i can think of to make the task happen but cant.

Comment: I am taking a different approach to this now